# HDMI out from laptop to DVI in on monitor

Tags: hdmi, dvi, adapter

I have a Vaio laptop with a Radeon HD 5650. It has HDMI out, while my SyncMaster 971p only has DVI in. I also have an HDMI to DVI cable.

When I connect the monitor with this cable to make an extended desktop, I am getting a 'Going to sleep' message on the monitor. Is there a way to make this combination work?

Comment: Laptops typically disable the external display outputs to conserve power and/or reduce EMI emissions.  You probably have to use a software command to enable the video output on that HDMI port.  One of the Function keys will probably also perform this function.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the HDMI output in your operating system.